# iOS push notifications using Node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, api, push-notification, npm

I am writing the Node server code for sending push notifications to an iOS device. when I run my code, it produces the error below. Has anyone seen this before or know how to handle it? If it helps give some context, I am using the 'apagent' node module. Thank you!

```
  crypto.js:145
  c.context.loadPKCS12(pfx);
            ^
  Error: Unable to load BIO
  at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:145:17)
  at Object.exports.connect (tls.js:1320:27)
  at Agent.connect (/Projects/api/node_modules/apnagent/lib/apnagent/agent/live.js:113:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/api/agent/_header.js:16:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
```